# vba, Why an un-dimensioned array works with Split()

Tags: arrays, vba

I can use an un-dimensioned String array with the Split() function to read fields from a String, but apparently, a String array has to be dimensioned to use it in a loop.

Why is that, and are there other situations where an array does not need to be dimensioned?

```
Dim field() As String
field = Split(data_line, "~")

Dim pref_line(10) As String
Input #1, pref_line(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

> but apparently, a String array has to be dimensioned to use it in a loop.

When use an un-dimensioned String array with the Split() function, the array is automatically dimensioned and values assigned to it. Also you can use that in a loop using `For i = LBound(field) to UBound(field)`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim field() As String
    Dim data_line As String

    data_line = "aaa~bbb"

    field = Split(data_line, "~")

    Debug.Print field(0)
End Sub
```

> Are there other situations where an array does not need to be dimensioned?

Yes. When you do not know how many items needs to be added to an array then you declare and un dimensioned array and `Redim Preserve` it to add values. For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim field() As Long
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    ReDim Preserve field(n)

    For i = 1 To 100
        field(n) = i
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve field(n)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @PradeepKumar youre right i think i might have not refreshed the page or an error ocurred. +1 where credit is due

Comment: @SiddharthRout prbably better to Redim every `n` loops by `n` extra items rather than each loop:)

Comment: @brettdj: You are absolutely correct. My intention was to display how to use `ReDim Preserve` when you do not know how many items needs to be added to an array (as I have mentioned in the post)

Answer (score 0):

`Split()` returns its own array regardless of what you defined before. You are effectively overwriting the value of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim field() As String` declares an array, but does not allocate it.

`Dim pref_line(10)` As String both declares and allocates it.

`field = Split(data_line, "~")` both allocates an array and populates it.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered your question, and correctly about what you asked for. So I won't comment on that.

On a side note, you should avoid Redimming arrays as much as possible. Do that only when absolutely necessary. Remember that it is just one line of code for us, but a whole lot of work for the runtime engine. First find a new contiguous memory location for the new array; then copy the array items from the old to new one; then discard the old array. So you see one `Redim Preserve` statement produces how much work for the compiler.

For this reason, redimming inside a loop is "usually" a bad idea, since you know in advance how many times the loop will run and how many elements you will have in the end. So in such cases, redim your array before the start of loop, rather than doing it inside the loop. The end result would be a better performance :)

Taking the code in @SiddharthRout 's reply as an example, notice that the Loop will produce 100 items since you are looping from 1 to 100. So instead of `ReDim Preserve field(n)` inside the loop, move that outside it before the start of loop. `ReDim Preserve field(100) as Long`, or simply `ReDim field(100) as Long`.

Comment: Pradeep that loop is an example. There are many scenarios where you don't know how long the loop may run and hence you have to use Redim in the loop ;)

Comment: Thanks, all. Great lesson that I couldn't have gotten by reading the documentation.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Yes you are right. Exactly why I started with the line that you have already got the answer to your question. :) This was just a general advice which most programmers miss and then wonder why their program is performing so slow.